# Trouble with vertical side-bar menu maintaining 100% height

Tags: css

I've been researching this problem and can't seem to find an answer that properly addresses my issue.  I have created a vertical sidebar menu which stays docked to the left side of the screen.  The menu has a different background color than the rest of the page and should be as tall as the entire page.  To accomplish this, I've used the CSS properties:

```
#menu {    
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

This works correctly, however, when elements are dynamically added to the body in such a way that they cause the height of the body to change, the height of the menu no longer takes up the entire screen.  Instead, I get white space below the dark background color of the menu.  This also occurs when I have the console open in Firefox and then scroll down.

How can I keep the vertical menu bar stretching down then entire side of the page?  None of the similar suggestions I've seen so far on Stackoverflow or Google seem to work.

Comment: Show us your HTML so that we can see for ourselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`height:100%;` takes up the view-port height so if your body content are increased than view-port height then you'll see your siderbar 100% heighty as its view-port as is.

You can just remove the `height:100%;` and your code would work fine, by using fixed positioning and using `top:0;bottom:0;` which would be the document's top and bottom values.

```
#menu {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  background-color: #222;
  position: fixed;/*using fixed positioning only works*/
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Also, don't forget to use the width while using fixed positioning, or alternatively, you may use left and right values.

Comment: You're right about the height not needing to be set to 100%.  I commented that out and it didn't negatively affect anything.  However, my main problem still persists.  When the document body is resized the vertical menu is no longer stretched full screen.

Comment: This definitely solves the issue I was dealing with.  However, it has the side effect of causing my menu links (which are nested in an unordered list) to scroll with the page as well.  Simply changing the css for <ul> element to "position: static;" didn't solve that issue either.

Comment: Fixed positioning of the menu items causes them to scroll when the page is scrolled as opposed to remaining static.  I want them to anchor to their positions so they don't move when I scroll the page.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `postion:sticky;` will help you then. But only applicable in newer browsers...otherwise you may use some scripting...

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help.  I put together a bit of a "hack" solution using your guidance.  It required an extra div, but everything looks and behaves the way I want it to now.